# Javascript works locally but bugs when uploaded to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

### I have googled, but couldn't find a solution

Trust me, I've googled!

So, what happens is the following: I have bought a 20 template pack, they are plain html/css & javascript, so I can open them without a webserver in my machine: They work fine.

The problem started when I uploaded a website to my server:

- Sliders won't show
- Hovering the 4 boxes right under "DISCOVER THE
  PLACES YOU’VE NEVER BEEN BEFORE" won't make them stand out
- Hovering Video or Gallery items won't apply a fade mask to the image
- Clicking on Video or Gallery won't open PrettyPortpholio overlay, instead it opens in another tab

Inspecting the website, I could see there was nothing linked wrong, all .js files were there, all images, the console don't output anything odd, it shows 2 little errors, but it's present in the template seller website as well, and it works there

This is my website:
[removed by user]

Template seller working website:
http://www.template-guide.com/preview/5500/

### I've uploaded another template from the same pack to see if it works, I get the exact same bugs:

Alternative bugged template:
[removed by user]

Alternative website from template seller: http://www.template-guide.com/preview/5501/

## Tried:

- Downloading jQuery and adding it locally (both 1.8.2 and last)
- Downloading again camera jQuery script (the .js responsible for the slider)
- Downloading an camera jQuery scrip adapted to the latest jQuery
- Googled, most issues were related to wrong path

Comment: I would suggest that you get your money back and find another source of assistance.

Comment: You don't happen to have javascript disabled for your website do you?
The example links for your server work just fine in chrome here.

Comment: Thanks @Josh, the problem was another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you will need to update twitter name in myscript.js.
Browse for this section

```
$('.tweet_module').tweet({
        modpath: 'twitter/',
        count: 2,
        username : 'your_name'
     });
```

and update "username : 'your_name'" or simply comment the above section, if you don't want to show twitter feeds. This causes an error in JS and the JS engine stops parsing anything after that.

Comment: That's it! Commenting the code out works!

I would never have found it, thanks a lot!!